# Is it possible to map Spring components through annotations using enums?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, enums

I'm working with Spring 4, and I have an enum declared like...

```
public static enum MY_ENUMS {
    A(1, "enum1"),
    B(2, "enum2");

    private final int key;
    private final String name;

    MY_ENUMS(int key, String name) {
        this.key = key;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return this.key;
    }
}
```

Then, from my component I'm *attempting* to do something like...

```
// @Named is the equivalent of @Component for this use case
// Making name public and trying this also does not work:
//   @Named(MY_ENUMS.A.name)
@Named(MY_ENUMS.A.getName())
public class ServiceImplA implements IService {

    @Override
    public Object interfaceMethod() {
        // Some code specific to ServiceImplA here....
    }
}
```

This doesn't build and I know **WHY** this doesn't build.  Basically, `MY_ENUMS.A.getName()` doesn't appear to the compilier as being constant, which would mean it cannot be used here.  But the point of enums is that they allow you a method to declare constants in a useful way.  So, with that being said, **is there a way I can specify my component's name by referring to the value in the enum?**

I feel this should be possible given that enums are a special case/implementation of constant values but I can't think of a way to work around Spring (or maybe Java's) expectation that the value of the annotation be a straight up constant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is there a way I can specify my component's name by referring to the
>   value in the enum?

No, there is not. If the annotation attribute was expecting an `enum`, you could just use the `enum`. But invoking a method does not resolve to a constant expression. You might think that you could make the field `public` and access it directly

```
@Named(MY_ENUMS.A.name)
```

but that won't work either because `MY_ENUMS.A.name` isn't a constant expression either.

The actual reason theat isn't a constant expression is that an enum constant is basically a variable. There is such a thing as a constant variable, which is a constant expression. For a variable to be a constant variable, it needs to be `final` and initialized with a constant expression. An `enum` constant is `final` but is not initialized with a constant expression. Basically an `enum` constant is compiled to

```
public static final YourEnum constant = new YourEnum();
```

The `new YourEnum()` expression is not a constant expression. And therefore the constant is not a constant variable and can't be used to resolve a `String` variable which it may be a constant variable.